# 1440x900 no longer available on my external display after "MLB for NVIDIA" fix

Tags: display

My early 2008 Macbook Pro was recently fixed for the known ["MLB for NVIDIA" issue](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2377). Since I've gotten my computer back, my external monitor no longer has the correct resolution available. This was working fine before. I've tried resetting PRAM and the problem still persists. Why?

Computer: Early 2008 Macbook Pro, OS X 10.5.8
Monitor: Acer 19"

Comment: I assume that the external display works, just that 1440x900 is not longer available? Are you using a DVI connector on the monitor or VGA?

Comment: @mjturner, I'm using a VGA connector.

Comment: I assume that's the same connector you were using before? I know this is clutching at straws a bit, but if your monitor has a DVI connector, can you perhaps try that instead?

Comment: Yes, it's the same connector. The monitor does not have a DVI connector, so that isn't an option.

Comment: FYI, I have no problem getting 1440x900 on a Dell using the same monitor.

Comment: Very strange. I would've suggested resetting the PRAM, but you've done that already. What resolutions do you see in System Preferences - all but 1440x900? Does Option-clicking on Displays help - I know that sometimes it can show options (eg, for rotation) that are hidden. Clutching at straws here!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this'll help (as the resolution should be available without resorting to third party software), but perhaps try [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html) and see if it makes the resolution available?

Comment: Yup, I tried that and 1440x900 still doesn't show up. Some resolutions that I get are 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x768, 1280x960, 1344x1008, 1400x1050, etc.

Comment: :( You can also create custom resolutions with SwitchResX - perhaps you can try that? Shouldn't be needed, but we're running out of ideas here...

Comment: I couldn't get the custom resolution to work either.